# Apple Mach-O Linker Error with Parse OBJC classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, linker

Hi I have looked over similar questions and tried everything but I can seem to fix my code. Every time I try and archive it I get

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Errors for Parse User, Object, File, Query, Parse  
and a linker command failed with exit code 1.
```

First I get an ld:

```
warning: ignoring file .., missing required architecture arm 64 in
file Parse.framework.Parse
```

Then the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFUser",
referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in SignupViewController.o
       objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
       objc-class-ref in InboxViewController.o
       objc-class-ref in EditFriendsViewController.o
       objc-class-ref in FriendsViewController.o
       objc-class-ref in CameraViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFObject", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in CameraViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFile", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in CameraViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFQuery", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in InboxViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please can someone with experience of this issue help me as I've spent about 3 hours researching this already.

I know it's something to do with the Linked Frameworks but I don't get what?

Things I've tried:

1. Updating to the latest version of Parse Framework.
2. Including various other Frameworks that might have been missing.
3. Changed the Architectures in Build Setting to Standard Architectures (armv7, arm64)
4. Changed Build active Architecture only to No.

I just want this X-code project to build and archive with 64-bit support but there seems to be something fundamentally wrong with how I'm implementing Parse for 64-bit

Comment: Is your framework in the "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase?

Comment: Your probably using an outdated version of Parse framework